# How can I explain "heimatdamisch"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I was swapping YouTube videos with a friend, and I showed Die Heimatdamisch, [Kids in Bavaria](https://youtu.be/O3D5yhttEjg).

Of course, I ***immediately*** "won" the "competition" (won one of my own beers).

Q: How do I translate/convey the feeling of "`Heimatdamisch`"?

Comment: What is that feeling expressed in terms of English words to you? They even sing in English... Sense of belonging? Local patriotism? Posh?

Comment: The English words are clear. I just don't know how to explain the name of the band to English speaking friends ...  OK, I can explain it, but they seem to want one word - like people who only speak one language often do

Comment: *Heimatdamisch* is a compound consisting of *Heimat* and *damisch*, both of which can be found in dictionaries (although *damisch* is southern German, so not all dictionaries may contain it).

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want for an answer. This seems to be a novel compound, meaning it's composed for a single use. Such compounds usually require at least two words to translate into English. Does the video or the contest have anything to do with the question, or are you just trying to translate the name? Band names are often inscrutable, being inside jokes or a reference only fans will understand. To translate a word properly you really need an example of the word being used in a sentence.

Comment: Anyway, I gather the "premise" of the band is to explore what would happen if American/British bands from the '80's (Cyndi Lauper, Kim Wilde, etc.) were actually south German polka bands. Apparently they're based in Bad Tölz, a town near the Austrian border.

Comment: Ich glaube es gibt nicht einmal eine perfekte Übersetzung für "Heimat", aber da wir trotzdem wissen, was das Wort bedeutet ist es hier off-topic, englische Worte dafür zu finden.

Comment: "`aber da ***wir*** trotzdem wissen`". Ihr schon, aber nicht jeder

Comment: Not "Die Heimatdamisch", but "[The Heimatdamisch](https://www.theheimatdamisch.de/)".

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Apologies of my mistake. Somehow that makes it seem even better :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"damisch" is bavarian dialect for "dämlich" (dim-witted, asinine) but that doesn't really convey the meaning of it. So the *can-be-looked-up-in-a-dictionary* comments are quite *damisch* themselves.

The word "damisch" has actually two meanings: it *can* be used with the meaning "asinine" (unlike "dämlich", which *only* has this meaning) with a connotation of "being confused" (a rather mild insult would i.e. be "Depp, damischer"), but in this context the meaning is another: to be passionate about something - to a point, where one is willing to appear *asinine* for others. The standard german counterpart would be the affix "-trunken", like in "freudetrunken" (overjoyed).

A native english-speaker can perhaps shed more light on this, to me a good translation would be "enthralled".

This seems to convey the idea of the band which covers pop pieces with the means of *Blasmusik* (or, rather, "Blåsmusi").

Comment: Thanks for that. I lived in Bavaria for 6 or 7 years, but never heard "damisch". Interesting

Comment: Just to make sure for learners... the word "dämlich" itself can NOT be used that way. It's always "dim witted".

Comment: @Emanuel: correct, thanks for the reminder. I added that to the answer.

Comment: I want to add, that "dämlich" is just a side-meaning of *damisch* with a low frequency of usage, at least in Austria, where the majority of native speakers of Bavarian dialects lives (almost 9 million Austrians speak Bavarian dialects, but only less than 7 million Germans (inhabitants of Altbayern)). The main meaning of *damisch* is "dizzy". In fact, *damisch* is a better translation for the english word *dizzy* than any standard German word. The Austrian commedian Thomas Maurer premiered a program entitled »Intensivdamisch« in 1998 and in ...

Comment: ... the [description of this program](https://thomasmaurer.at/de/programme/intensivdamisch) he wrote: *»damisch: ugs. benommen, unausgeschlafen, verstört«* (*damisch:* colloquial dazed, unrested, disturbed) and [ostarrichi.org](https://www.ostarrichi.org/suche?search=damisch) lists *»verwirrt, benommen«* (confused, dazed) for good reason as first meaning. The second meaning (dumm = stupid) just derives from the the dizziness that is the main meaning of *»damisch«.*

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to go for a name with similar connotations, I'd try for "The Patridiots".  Grammatically, "Patridiotic" would be closer, but "idiotic" is too much in specifically non-colloquial language domain to fit the regional "damisch" well.  The problem with using "home" as translation of "Heimat" is that "Heimat" never means a single building or homestead while that's the main connotation of "home".  "Heimat" is always a geographical term (country, region, township, or similar) as opposed to "Heim".

Answer (score 0):

As an American, who's studied German... The nearest that I can get that the band attempting was a word play on; "nut·house" as per the definition; a home or hospital for people with mental illnesses.

---

Addition: the American colloquialism for nuthouse... That being a happy home, with term "happy" eluding to crazy.

Comment: Welcome to German SE! You can always edit your previous answer. I'm don't think I agree with your interpretation idea here though. For once "Heimat" and "Heim" are two very different words. "Heimat" refers to something like a town, region or country, so "nut house" and "Heimat" aren't really compatible. Also, the order of words doesn't really fit. It's like saying that the word "homegrown" refers to a grown home or a home for grown people. It doesn't work that way around.

Answer (score 0):

A good translation of Heimat damisch would be "homeland-mad/crazy" with damisch/mad or crazy both conveying the two meanings: "utterly enthralled" and "meshuggene". God bless you all down to the seventh generations of the fruit of your loins.

Comment: I believe homeland has quite different connotations than Heimat. Unrelated praise of your preferred deity are not suitable in postings here

Answer (score -1):

Based on their music and videos, I would guess that a very rough American translation would be The Village Idiots.  It could also allude to someone at home in their confusion.  Heimat does not always refer to a specific geographical area, but more a place where someone feels truly at home.  Damisch is a bit more difficult, as it is primarily a Bavarian dialect. Dim, confused, crazy would all fit the bill in their own way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

They're a delight, aren't they, The Heimatdamisch? It's being such precise musicians that makes their comedy so irresistible.

I too have been wondering about their name. Wikipedia gives some support for Heimat not exclusively connoting homeland but also home:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heimat
In that case I wonder if it derives from COVID lockdown conditions when so many people felt they were going mad stuck at home. In which case perhaps an idiomatic translation would be 'stir crazy'.

However, the oom-pah polka band is also to most people an egregiously crazy feature of south German culture; so, The Bayern Berserkers.

Comment: No, just no. This doesn't provide an answer, and the speculation is easily falsifiable when looking at how long the band exists. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Heimatdamisch

Comment: Fair comment. I did wonder if they'd been around that much longer.